# Can you install Spore on multiple computers?

Tags: spore

I have just put a copy of Spore on eBay. Someone has already messaged me asking if there will be any issues installing it on their computer if it has already been installed on mine.

Will there be any issues registering and installing this game on another computer?

Comment: Why would you ever want to install spore on any computer ever...

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to resell Spore and install it on another computer, however, there are a few caveats.

EA dislikes resale of games because it hurts their revenue, and they try to discourage it as best they can.

For example, as Spore can only be installed 5 times in total, every time you installed it will be subtracted from that figure. The new owner will be able to install it only 4 times or less.

Additionally, other restrictions may be placed like no technical support, limited online capabilities and so on.

For more information, see this article on Ars Technica: [EA skirts first-sale doctrine with limits on resale of Spore](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2008/09/ea-skirts-first-sale-doctrine-with-limits-on-resale-of-spore.ars).